# Swift/iOS - reply on notification fails

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I've implemented **Remote Push notifications** *(apn)* to my application so that I can send notifications from a server to the client.

My app is kind of a messenger like whatsapp or telegram and so I want the client to be able to answer to the notifications. So I've implemented a **NotificationService** extension.

If I press the notification, input my message into the appearing text field and click the answer button *(like we all know it from our favorite messenger application)* I want the message to be send to back to my server.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   // on reply
   if let url = URL(string: "myserver/send/text") {
       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
         if let serverResult = data as? String {
           print("success")
         }
       }
       task.resume() 
   }
}
```

This method is working sometimes but I noticed that I got some problems if the application is closed or my iphone is locked: The URL does not get fetched with this code.

With the debugger I've found something very interesting in the logs: **Software caused connection abort**.

How can I fix this problem? Will it change something if I implement sockets? Why does this work for clients like telegram/whatsapp but not for me? What in the world am I doing wrong? :-(

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a background session data task for that if you want downloads/uploads to progress after your app is no longer in foreground. The basic constraints of background sessions are outlined in URL Session Programming Guide: [Using NSURLSession: Background Transfer Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44), and are essentially:

1. Use delegate-based URLSession with background URLSessionConfiguration.
2. Use upload and download tasks only, with no completion handlers.
3. Implement `application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)` in your app delegate, saving the completion handler and starting your background session.
4. Implement `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` in your URLSessionDelegate, calling that saved completion handler to let OS know you're done processing the background request completion.

Also, put your attention to the fact, that background upload tasks can work with files only. They will immediately fail if you'll try to upload a byte array in form of Data object from the memory.